# jQuery confirmation dialog from gridview row always posts back

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to delete a row in gridview using an imagebutton like this

```
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" CssClass="gridColumnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imgs/Delete.png" AlternateText="Delete"  
                            CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have written jQuery dialog for confirmation of delete like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
confirm();
    });

    function confirm() {
        $(".gridColumnDelete").click(function () {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        __doPostBack(); 
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }

            });
        });
        return false;
    }
```

the div tag used for dialog is this

```
 <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirm?" style="display:none">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure to delete the trip?</p>
</div>
```

the problem is whether i click Yes or cancel in dialog the Gridview_RowCommand is executed in c#.

In fact Gridview_RowCommand is executed even before i click on any button in the confirmation dialog

Comment: I'm not sure if `__doPostBack();` will work like you want it to, but try putting the `return false;` inside the click handler.

Comment: return is moved inside Yes and cancel function as suggested but no luck

Comment: Have you tried using the property `OnClientClick` for your `ImageButton`? It should fire before the postback.

Answer (score 1):

remove the return statement at the end and do as below

```
"Yes": function () {
   // __doPostBack(); 
    $(this).dialog("close");
    return true;
},
"Cancel": function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    return false;
}
```

And change your `asp:ImageButton` as below

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete"  OnClientClick="return confirm();" CssClass="gridColumnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imgs/Delete.png" AlternateText="Delete"  
                            CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"/>
```

Comment: it posts back even before i click on any button in the confirmation dialog

Comment: still not working with jQuery. now only i noticed that confirm is a javascript function. so now the default confirm message is showing now. but not the jQuery function. i changed the name to ConfirmDelete and changed OnClientClick="return confirmDelete();" but still not working

Answer (score 1):

```
"Yes": function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    return true;
},
"Cancel": function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    return false;
}

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete"  OnClientClick="return confirm();" CssClass="gridColumnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imgs/Delete.png" AlternateText="Delete"  
                            CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem using the below link in 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238122/Delete-Functionality-in-GridView-with-Confirmation
[CodeProject][1]